# NodeJs приложние при старте из Putty в OS CentOs как сделать чтобы не выключалось при выходе из putty без стороннего софта?

Tags: node.js

Знаю что есть сторонние приложения для решения это задачи, например pm2.
При этом мне бы просто сделать чтобы при запуске из putty приложение выполнялось вне моей сессии putty и следовательно не прекращало бы работу когда я выхожу из putty.
Есть ли какой флаг для запуска NodeJs приложения таким способом?

Уточню, что предполагаю, что после такого запуска я не увижу что NodeJs выводит через console.log в putty но мне и не нужно, то есть мне и нужно чтобы после запуска приложения NodeJs управление было возвращено Putty и я бы смог далее выполнять команды.
Как убить процесс по kill я знаю, а так же как найти PID приложения по используемым портам, чтобы потом его убить. Мне именно запустить нужно.

Сейчас я делаю так:

1. используя команду cd выбираю нужную папку например cd /node
2. выполняю например node index.js для запуска. Вот к этой команде может быть есть какой то флаг чтобы управление сразу вернулось в putty?

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте скрипт для запуска

```
#!bin/bash
node index.js > /dev/null &
```